# CNAME Domain Mapping/forwarding in a Saas Application

Tags: apache, server, saas, cname

I am trying to provide a feature for my users to map their custom domain [ which they will will purchase themselves ] and to their profile/page on my website say client.foo.com, using CNAME domain forwarding.

I have gone through various questions on StackOverflow regarding the same problem but all have focused on creating wildcard subdomains which I have already done and they function well.

**Assumptions:**

1. I am currently on a shared hosting, hence shared IP. [I can purchase a dedicated IP if that does the job efficiently.].
2. I am using apache server hence please suggest the solutions considering the same.

---

A better explanation of My issue - [Taken from other StackOverflow question, but solutions not as requested]:

I host at fooservice.com. For each user, they get their own subdomain bob.fooservice.com. I'm pretty sure I can get that part covered. Let's also assume that Bob wants the service to appear as a subdomain of his site awesomebob.com. He wants it to be foo.awesomebob.com. I know that what Bob has to do is add a CNAME record from foo.awesomebob.com -> bob.fooservice.com. My question is what do I have to do to make sure that valuable on my fooservice server.

*Thank you for all your valuable suggestion well in advance.*

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation, you use wildcard subdomains, which all have the same IP I assume and you want to automate the process right?

So, as CNAME record is only pointing to the IP address, not redirecting, you need to create virtual host in the first order than other virtual host.

In this virtual host, create a script (index.php) to serve the correct subdomain's page from the requested custom domain.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But as mentioned I am on shared hosting hence creating a virtual host for the purpose seems difficult (Correct me if I am wrong.)

Secondly, if required do let me know to shift to VPS or anything similar for getting the job done.